# Giving file path to the button as command in GUI Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi i need to open a python script using GUI. Is that possible to give the file path as command to the button? I tried with the below code, but it is showing  No such file or directory. Please help
Thank you

```
import xlwt
from Tkinter import *            
from tkFileDialog   
import askopenfilename      

def callback():
    filename = ('C:\python\abc.py')
    execfile(filename)

abc= Button(text='abc', command=callback)
abc.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash is the escape character, so you should escape it to make it mean "backslash the character" and not "backslash the escape character". Try assigning `filename` like this:

```
filename = ('C:\\python\\abc')
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming directory `c:\python` and the file `abc` exist, you could also try a raw string:

```
filename = (r'C:\python\abc')
```

Aside: If I were to see that path, I'd assume `python\abc` was a path and the file was missing (partially because `abc` doesn't have an extension).